# Expansion of $\det(A+B)$

Tags: reference-request, matrices, determinants

If $A,B\in{\bf M}_n(k)$, then the following formula holds true:
$$\det(A+B)=\sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{|I|=|J|=r}\epsilon(I,I^c)\epsilon(J,J^c)A\binom IJ B\binom{I^c}{J^c}.$$
In this formula, $I$ and $J$ are ordered (increasingly) $r$-uplets in $[1,n]$, $A\binom IJ$ is the corresponding minor, $I^c$ is the ordered complement of $I$ and $\epsilon(I,I^c)$ is the signature of the permutation thus defined.

> I should like to have a reference for this formula. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The formula appears in

Marvin Marcus "determinants of sums". College mathematics journal, March 1990.

https://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/determinants-of-sums

The author notes that it is hard to track it's origins, but mentions previous references in the text, in particular to a book of himself in 1975.

Comment: Astonishing ! I keep amazed by the efficiency of MO. Thanks a lot.